# Сборка OpenCV, MSVC15

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opencv

Столкнулся с такой проблемой при сборке OpenCV, вчера собирал её без CUDA и она собиралась нормально. Сегодня после установки CUDA не могу нормально собрать, большая часть DLL и lib не собрались. MSVC тоже выдает ошибки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Лог сборки: https://pastebin.com/yQ7YvBwB

Comment: Приведите лог сборки.

Comment: @VTT, попробовал собрать еще раз. Опять все с ошибками. Глянул уже ошибки там, он просто не мог открыть некоторые lib файлы, глянул build, там поискал, а этих файлов не было. Значит cmake не собрал их. Пробую еще раз. На второй машине все также.